# MySql no Datasource appears in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2015

I want to use MySql with Visual Studio 2015 Community following this [tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-making-a-connection.html).
The Problem is i dont see, the "MySql Database" in the Data Source list, there is no ".NET Framework Data Provider for MySQL" in the Data Provider list as well.

Has anybody an idea?

Comment: u use mysql .net connector?

Comment: Yes, i installed MySQL Connector Net 6.9.9 and MySQL for Visual Studio 2.0.3

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/ use this link to download the connector

Comment: same problem happened with me but after downloaded from this website i got the result

Comment: After installing then restart your deskstop

Comment: from which website? i uninstalled MySQL Connector Net 6.9.9 and MySQL for Visual Studio 2.0.3 and installed the version in the link above and restarted, but nothing changed for me... still no datasource appears

Comment: First go to view then server exploser then choose add new connection after right clicking and then mysql database option choose

Comment: nothing changed... i dont see this option in the listbox. What exactly do you have installed and which versions of it? You use VS 2015 community?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128562/discussion-between-prashant-kumar-singh-and-kyi).

Comment: i am using 2015

Comment: in server explorer their is data connection so right click on data-connect after that add new connection and one thing go to task manager then in service and in service their mysql and u have stop this mysql for successfull connection